# How to choose the virtual host Apache points HTTPS connections to?

Tags: apache-2.2

I've just activated a test SSL certificate on my local Apache 2 installation, by following these steps:

- Uncommenting the line `Include conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf` in httpd.conf
- Generating and copying server.crt and server.key to the conf directory

I restarted Apache and got the test page which is hosted in the `htdocs` directory.

**How can I make Apache return one of my virtual hosts instead?**

My virtual hosts currently look like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain.localhost
    DocumentRoot c:\www\domain
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have it point to the existing port 80 virtual host - you'll need to set up a port 443 virtual host.  There might already be one in the `http-ssl.conf` that it's using.